# Aligning an equation in two places

Tags: align, alignat, multline

I have an equation that I want to look something like

```
a = b
  = c
  = 1/n[a_1 +
        a_2 +
        a_3 +
        ... +
        a_n]
```

That is, I'd like the = signs to be aligned, and I'd like to align the a_ns as well. I suspect that the alignat environment is what I'd want to use here. What's throwing me off is that there's just blank space before each a_i, so there's not the "grid alignment" present here that alignat and align are built for. I'd really appreciate any help, and I hope my question is clear. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you check all the related questions to the right, this almost qualifies as a FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote

> I'd like the `=` signs to be aligned, and I'd like to align the `a_n`s as well.

Here's a solution that nests an `aligned` environment in an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
  &= c\\
  &= 1/n[\begin{aligned}[t]
           &a_1 +{} \\
           &a_2 +{} \\
           &a_3 +{} \\
           &{\dotsb}+{} \\
           &a_n]
         \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work well with `alignat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
a & = b                     \\
  & = c                     \\
  & = 1/n [ & a_1 & + {}    \\
  &         & a_2 & + {}    \\
  &         & a_3 & + {}    \\
  &         & \hdots & + {} \\
  &         & a_n &]
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may consider to replace `\hdots` with `\dotsm`. (+1)